# Godot, GDscript: why can't I reference a dictionary that I JUST declared in this snippet?

Tags: godot, gdscript

```
var fdic = {}
var r1 = funcref(self,"f1")
fdic.fref1 = r1
fdic.fref1.call_func()
```

f1 is a function in my script.
I declare fdic but then I get an 'Unexpected Token: Identifier: fdic' error.

Answer (score 0):

You can only make declarations outside of function bodies, not execute arbitrary code. Move your code inside some function in your class file.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably (since you have statements and GDScript does not support top level statements) your code is inside a method, something like this:

```
func something() -> void:
    var fdic = {}
    var r1 = funcref(self,"f1")
    fdic.fref1 = r1
    fdic.fref1.call_func()

func f1() -> void:
    #using fdic here causes an error
    pass
```

Then the problem is that `fdic` is a local variable of the first method. And no, `funcref` does not capture it.

Simplest solution would be to make it a field (script variable) like this:

```
var fdic:Dictionary

func something() -> void:
    fdic = {}
    var r1 = funcref(self,"f1")
    fdic.fref1 = r1
    fdic.fref1.call_func()

func f1() -> void:
    #using fdic here is OK
    pass
```

Which might or might not be correct (depending on recursion). So, perhaps it is better to make it a parameter:

```
func something() -> void:
    var fdic = {}
    var r1 = funcref(self,"f1")
    fdic.fref1 = r1
    fdic.fref1.call_func(dfic)

func f1(fdic:Dictionary) -> void:
    #using fdic here is OK
    pass
```